# Why there is ListVIew in android?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

My question is that we have `ListView` and `Gridview` in android.

> List view as

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Now suppose I setup everything for `ListView` i.e adapter , created data for list.
Now instead of `ListView` just replace the `GridView` as

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:numColumns="1"/>
```

> `GridView` act like `ListView` then why there is `ListView` ,if we can achive all the functionality of `ListView` by `GridView` assinging `android:numCloumns="1"`? Any specific use of list?

**I know `GridView` is used to arrange the item in row and column.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Android developer [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html), the parent class for both ListView and Gridiew is same and that is `android.widget.AbsListView`. 
 Now this class that can be used to implement virtualized lists of items. And subclases of this class can display the content of the list in a grid, in a carousel, as stack, etc.

So from Development's view, as you already pointed out, you may be able to achieve same effect by either of them.

> Perhaps, answer to this lies in Design of Application and has more to
>   do with User experience in certain use cases.

A list style layout is for those users whose actions tend to be very singular in purpose. They've come to your Application to do one thing: browse or read. Present them with content in a standard way and let them just get lost in it. 
On the other hand, grid view is for the quick access of content. It's for the restless and curious. Your attention goes from one topic or image to the next and you never want to linger in one spot for too long. And when you get tired of standing, you just click into your topic of interest for more details and have a seat so you can take your time and become completely enthralled.

In a Nutshell, List view provides users a format that follows user's natural reading patterns, while grid view is a little more interruptive, making it best suited for visual content. You can jump from one image to the next without worrying about order or continuity. It's all about discovery and just seeing everything.

Check what is more important in YOUR Application's data. For **image** based content the best option is the grid view. For data based content a better option is the list view.

Also, Grid View offers an additional functionality: grid lists may scroll either vertically or horizontally.

So apart from User Experience Grid view also offers more flexibility if required!

Comment: i understand what you said, but other than UX is there any major diffrence ?

Comment: @Nilesh: Yes, apart from UX, Grid View also offers an additional functionality: grid lists may scroll either vertically or horizontally. This perhaps offers more flexibility if App requires!! I edited the Answer to add this Point too!